# Add base classes to "New C++ Class" dialog

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse:

When I select In "File/New/Class/Add...",

I can see base class candidates from boost::, std::, sql::, and my current project.

I would like to add the Gnome classes (Gtk::, Glib::, etc.) to the list of candidates. Anybody know how to do that?

Comment: Oops...accidentally deleted the [FAQ] quoting comment by Rob. This question is firmly on-topic for Stack Overflow: *"if your question generally covers … software tools commonly used by programmers … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"*

Comment: What's the relationship between the Gnome files and your project? Are they in the project's include path? Another project in your workspace?

Comment: Include and library files are specified via strings like `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs` in the project properties g++ tool settings.

Comment: BTW, I'm late responding to Dynguss' question because I'm not getting email notifications of the added comments. I checked my profile and it does have a good, working email address.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse CDT will only offer you classes to choose from if its indexer knows about them. To be able to add Gnome classes you might need to add the corresponding include directories to your project's include path (project->properties->c++ build->settings->c++ compiler->includes ...)

If you have done that already, you might try to rebuild the index for your project. If you use such a class you want to inherit from and can CTRL-click its name and jump to its definition/declaration then the index should be OK.

However, if Gnome will have headers that are hard to parse for CDT (e.g. macro settings required before you can use them), you might still have problems. I have no experience with Gnome to actually tell you if it is so.